# Add the retag button back after getting the edit question privilege

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface

After I got the [Edit Questions and Answers](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/edit) question privilege the retag button is gone in questions.

I have used it for a long time and liked it.  Maybe add it back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, it is the decision of Stack Exchange team to  encourage improvements in post, instead of just retagging it. Alternatively you can use this script for quickly retag:

http://shog9.com/greasemonkey/scripts/so_quick_retag.user.js